# Layer which works on single sample to layer which works on batches

Tags: python, tensorflow

I currently have a layer like the following:

```
class MyLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__()

    def call(self, img, params):
        tf.foo(img)
        tf.bar(img, params)
        return img
```

The call method gets and input `img` with shape `(128, 128, 3)` and `params` with shape `(15)`.

What do I have to change such that the layer can operate on batches? The input `img` would for example have shape `(32, 128, 128, 3)` and `params` would have shape `(32, 15)`.

So the question is basically: how do I have to edit the layer such that it does the same stuff it does now but for each image in a batch?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you simply wanna reshape the size of the image tensor??
what you wanna do would be something like, x=np.reshape(x,(32,128,128,3)). 
Lemme know if that helps.

Comment: I want to know how I can edit the above layer such that it does the stuff I wrote for each image in the batch.

Comment: you really need to give more code, and why would you want to concatenate image and params?

Answer (score 0):

Well by default your layer should recognize the tensor coming from the previous layer and be able to make sure its input shape conforms to that spec:
i.e.

```
(None, 128,128,3)
```

So the batch size shouldn't matter. Your problem is most likely that you have no build() function as well as you're not passing **kwargs through your init and its super.

Also, the call() should only have self and x as arguments, if you need more than one input, you should use a concatenation layer before it to push the two tensors together, or make a list with them

Comment: How do I concatenate `imgs` and `params`  if the shape is different?